# Winsock manually send HTTP request gives 403 Forbidden

Tags: c++, winsock, winsock2

I am currently trying to understand how HTTP requests work so I am using winsock2 for c++ to try and send some HTTP requests manually.

My code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

#include "EasyWinSock.h"



char ip[] = "prnt.sc";
char port[] = "80"; 

int main() {

    easy_win_sock ews(ip, port); 

    ews.init_win_sock(); 
    ews.create_win_sock(); 
    ews.connect_win_sock(); 


    char sendbuf2[] = "GET /t/gh17d-1645175682/post HTTP/1.1\r\nUser-Agent: kekwtestkekw\r\nHost: ptsv2.com\r\n\r\n"; 
    char sendbuf[] = "GET /111111 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.prnt.sc\r\n\r\n"; 


    ews.send_win_sock(sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf)); 

    DATA *result = ews.recieve_win_sock_text(512); // dynamically allocated

    /*
    for (int i = 0; i < result->content->size(); i++) {
        std::cout << (*result->content)[i];
    }
    */

    ews.cleanup_win_sock(); 

    return 0;
}
```

With the Winsocket tucked away in the struct:

```
#pragma once

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>


struct DATA {
    std::vector<char*>* content; 
    int size; 
};

struct easy_win_sock {
    char *ip; 
    char *port;

    WSADATA *wsaData; 

    addrinfo* result = nullptr;
    addrinfo* ptr = nullptr;

    SOCKET *sock; 


    easy_win_sock(char* ip, char* port) {
        this->ip = ip; 
        this->port = port; 

        this->sock = new SOCKET; 
        this->wsaData = new WSADATA;

    }

    void init_win_sock() {
        

        int i_result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), wsaData);
        if (i_result != 0) {
            std::cout << "WASStartup failed: " << i_result << std::endl;
            exit(1); 
        }
    }

    void create_win_sock() {
        this->result = NULL;
        this->ptr = NULL;
        addrinfo hints;

        ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
        hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
        hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

        // get ip adress of hostname 
        int i_result = getaddrinfo(this->ip, this->port, &hints, &this->result);
        if (i_result != 0) {
            std::cout << "getaddrinfo failed: " << i_result << std::endl;
            WSACleanup();
            exit(1); 
        }

        // create socket
        *this->sock = INVALID_SOCKET;

        // Attempt to connect to the first adress returned by the call to getaddrinfo
        this->ptr = this->result;

        // create socket for connecting to server
        *this->sock = socket(this->ptr->ai_family, this->ptr->ai_socktype, this->ptr->ai_protocol);

        if (*this->sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            std::cout << "Error at socket(): " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
            freeaddrinfo(this->result);
            WSACleanup();
            exit(1); 
        }
    }


    void connect_win_sock() {
        // connect to server
        int i_result = connect(*this->sock, this->ptr->ai_addr, (int)this->ptr->ai_addrlen);
        if (i_result == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            closesocket(*this->sock);
            *this->sock = INVALID_SOCKET;
        }

        // if connection failed we just close everithing instead of trying other adresses from getadressinfo()
        freeaddrinfo(result);

        if (*this->sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            std::cout << "Unable to connect to server!" << std::endl;
            WSACleanup();
            exit(1); 
        }

    }

    void send_win_sock(char* data, int buf_len) {
        int i_result = send(*this->sock, data, buf_len, 0);
        if (i_result == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            std::cout << "Send failed: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
            closesocket(*this->sock);
            WSACleanup();
            exit(1); 
        }

    }

    DATA* recieve_win_sock_text(int buf_size) {

        std::vector<char*>* recvbufs = new std::vector<char*>; 
        DATA* data = new DATA;

        // recieve data till server closes connection 
        int i_result = 1;  // number of recieved bytes
        while (i_result > 0) {
            recvbufs->push_back(new char[buf_size]); 
            i_result = recv(*this->sock, (*recvbufs)[recvbufs->size() - 1], buf_size - 1, 0);
            if (i_result >= 0) {
                (*recvbufs)[recvbufs->size() - 1][i_result] = '\0'; 
                std::cout << (*recvbufs)[recvbufs->size() - 1];
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "recv failed: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
            }
        }

        data->content = recvbufs; 
        return data; 
    }

    void cleanup_win_sock() {
        // shutdown the connection for sending 
        // still can recieve
        int i_result = shutdown(*this->sock, SD_SEND);
        if (i_result == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            std::cout << "Shutdown failed: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
            closesocket(*this->sock);
            WSACleanup();
            exit(0); 
        }

        closesocket(*this->sock);
        WSACleanup();

        delete this->sock; 
        delete this->wsaData; 
    }
};
```

I am using **http://ptsv2.com/** to try out my HTTP requests and on this site they work. When I however try to send a GET request to the site **prnt.sc/111111** I get different Error codes depending on my GET request. When I just do a

```
GET /111111 HTTP/1.1
Host: prnt.sc
<empty line>
```

for example, I get a 403 Forbidden.

When I use the Website **https://reqbin.com/** to test HTTP requests and i put in **prnt.sc/111111** it generates the same request but the response it shows is 200 OK.

Can anyone help me? I'm seriously stuck here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You do a lot of things that you don't need to do, like creating the `SOCKET` and `WSADATA` dynamically. You should also not use `char*` for strings in C++, but `std::string`. You almost *never* need pointers to standard containers. The `DATA` structure just doesn't seem needed. And why `#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yeah I know I know... I wanted to use SMFL for something afterwards but got stuck on the http request. And the rest is just quickly done in order to experiment. For now I just want to get the HTTP requests working. (But out of curiosity: How would I go about not creating the Socket dynamically. I mean I do need to use it in different functions)

Comment: HTTP could be more complex than initially thought. I suggest a library such as [libcurl](https://curl.se/libcurl/). Don't spend more time reinventing the wheel when you could be concentrating on your actual program instead. :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yeah I probably gonna use something like libcurl in the future but first I'm gonna looks if anyone can help me understand pure HTTP requests.

Comment: I know some web sites that check the "User-Agent" line to find out if the request comes from a web browser or from a tool. If the "User-Agent" line does not contain a known web browser, those sites return 403.

Comment: @MartinRosenau is it possible to just copy the User-Agent text from an HTTP request sent by a web browser? Because every time I try to do it, the site returns a 302 Found Error…

Comment: 4xx are errors; 3xx means that the URL has changed; in the case of 302 there should be a a line "Location: ..." in the response containing the real URL.

Comment: @MartinRosenau in my ip i habe prnt.sc and in my GET section I have /111111 and in my Host section I have prnt.sc. But when I get the 302 the location section just says Location prnt.sc/111111 . So basically the same as I put in. Thats what I dont understand